# Why is Pyproj giving me infinity values?

Tags: python, gis, utm, pyproj

I'm trying to convert from UTM coordinates (WGS84, zone 18N) to latitude and longitude. I'm using the following code:

```py
from pyproj import Proj
x = [230144.41150306776]
y = [3989937.673933774]
wgs84 = Proj(proj="utm", zone=18, ellps="WGS84")
lat, lon = wgs84(x, y)
print(lon)
print(lat)
```

But the output is:

```
[inf]
[inf]
```

Why does this produce infinity values? I feel like I'm doing something backwards.

Comment: Could it be that your coordinates are out of range?  I know absolutely nothing about this stuff, but [this web site](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-18n/) suggests that valid coordinates fall within a range that uses only two whole number digits.  I've entered smaller number as x, y in your code, and it gives back non-`inf` numbers as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add inverse=True like this : wgs84(x, y, inverse=True)
if inverse is True the inverse transformation from x/y to lon/lat is performed. Default is False.